# max/min function on list with strings and integers

Tags: python, string, list

I've got a list with strings and integers and want to find the minimum value of the integers, without list-slicing. Is there a work-around?

```
arr = [5,3,6,"-",3,"-",4,"-"]    
for i in range(len(set(arr))):
        cut = min(arr)
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could filter the non numeric using a generator expression:

```
arr = [5,3,6,"-",3,"-",4,"-"]
result = min(e for e in arr if isinstance(e, int))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
3
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way using directly the `max` and `min` built-in funtions with a custom `key`:

```
arr = [5,3,6,"-",3,"-",4,"-"]
max(arr, key=lambda x: (isinstance(x,int), x))
# 6
```

And similarly for the `min`:

```
min(arr, key=lambda x: (not isinstance(x,int), x))
# 3
```

---

**Details**

For the min, consider the following list comprehension as an "equivalent" of the transformation applied with the `key`:

```
sorted([(not isinstance(x,int), x) for x in arr])

[(False, 3),
 (False, 3),
 (False, 4),
 (False, 5),
 (False, 6),
 (True, '-'),
 (True, '-'),
 (True, '-')]
```

So the `min` will be the lowest tuple, i.e. `(0,3)`.

And for the `max`, the highest will be `(1,6)`:

```
sorted([(isinstance(x,int), x) for x in arr])

[(False, '-'),
 (False, '-'),
 (False, '-'),
 (True, 3),
 (True, 3),
 (True, 4),
 (True, 5),
 (True, 6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `list` into `set` to speed up calculations:

```
min(i for i in set(arr) if isinstance(i, int))
```

#### Benchmark:

```
setup = "arr = [5, 3, 6,'-', 3,'-', 4, '-'] * 1000"

solution1 = "min(i for i in set(arr) if isinstance(i, int))"
solution3 = "min(e for e in arr if isinstance(e, int))"
solution2 = "min(arr, key=lambda x: (not isinstance(x,int), x))"

print(timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=solution1, number=10000))
print(timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=solution2, number=10000))
print(timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=solution3, number=10000))
```

Output:

```
1.0895615029
13.389633473
22.653398585
```

If you have only one type of string:

```
min(set(arr) - {'-'})
```